# Как вывести сумму последовательности? python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как вывести сумму последовательности?

Например, ввод: 12
Последовательность 12=1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12, ее сумма должна составить ровно 12 или на одну последовательность выше. В нашем варианте: сумма 12 будет равна 1+2+3+4+5=15

Другими словами: необходимо создать код, который вычисляет сумму последовательных чисел 1 + 2 + 3 + ... до тех пор, пока ее значение не станет хотя бы числом, введенным пользователем.

Comment: Что значит, _сумма `1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12` должна составить ровно 12 или на одну последовательность выше_ и следующее утверждение `сумма 12 будет равна 1+2+3+4+5=15`?  Сумма арифметической последовательности от 1 до 12 будет `(a1 + aN) * N / 2 = (1 + 12) * 12 / 2 = 78`, от 1 до 5 соответственно 15.

Comment: Вы знаете сумму арифметической прогрессии? А квадратные уравнения решать умеете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если брут-форсом, то так:

```
n, i = int(input()), 0
while sum(range(i)) < n:
    i += 1
else:
    print(sum(range(i)))
```

Для реально больших чисел, конечно, можно придумать более эффективный алгоритм, но над этим уже думайте сами.

Comment: Зачем использовать `else`?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Сам не знаю) Просто так добавил, для красоты. Программа и с ним хорошо работает.

Answer (score 4):

Сумма арифметической прогрессии от *1* до *n* равна *n(n + 1)/2*. Требуется для заданного *s* отыскать минимальное *n: n(n + 1)/2 ≥ s*.

*n<sup>2</sup> + n ≥ 2s*  — раскрываем скобки.

*4n<sup>2</sup> + 4n ≥ 8s*

*(2n)<sup>2</sup> + 2(2n) + 1 - 1 ≥ 8s*

*(2n + 1)<sup>2</sup> - 1 ≥ 8s*

*(2n + 1)<sup>2</sup> ≥ 1 + 8s*

*2n + 1 ≥ √(1 + 8s)* — нас интересует только один, положительный, корень из квадрата.

*2n + 1 ≥ ⌈√(1 + 8s)⌉* — cлева целое число, значит и выражение справа можно округлить вверх.

*2n ≥ ⌈√(1 + 8s)⌉ - 1*

*n ≥ (⌈√(1 + 8s)⌉ - 1)/2*

*n ≥ ⌈(⌈√(1 + 8s)⌉ - 1)/2⌉* — cлева целое число, значит и выражение справа можно округлить вверх.

*n = ⌈(⌈√(1 + 8s)⌉ - 1)/2⌉* — ищем минимальное *n*, можно заменить неравенство на равенство.

Нужно вычислить *⌈√n⌉*, где *n* целое. [math.isqrt](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isqrt) вычисляет *⌊√n⌋ = `math.isqrt(n)`*. Там же можно найти совет для округления вверх: *⌈√n⌉ = `math.isqrt(n - 1) + 1`*.

Второе неочевидное место: *⌈n/2⌉*, где *n* целое. Оператор [`//`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) делит округляя вниз: *⌊n/2⌋ = `n // 2`*. А нам нужно вверх: *⌈n/2⌉ = `(n + 1) // 2`*.

Подставим операции языка программирования в формулу:

*n = ⌈(⌈√(1 + 8s)⌉ - 1)/2⌉*

*n = ⌈(math.isqrt(1 + 8s - 1) + 1 - 1)/2⌉*

*n = (math.isqrt(1 + 8s - 1) + 1 - 1 + 1) // 2*

*n = (math.isqrt(8s) + 1) // 2*

```
import math

s = int(input())
n = (math.isqrt(8 * s) + 1) // 2
m = n * (n + 1) // 2
print(m)
```